# Prove that $|\sin\,(\text{Re}\,z)|\le|\sin z|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How do you prove that $|\sin\,(\text{Re}\,z)|\le|\sin z|$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$? I know that $|\text{Re}\,z|\le|z|$ but then what? Even a hint will help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $z=a+ib$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. One may write
$$
\begin{align}
|\sin z|&=|\sin(a+ib)|
\\&=|\sin a \cdot \cos(ib)+\sin (ib) \cdot \cos a|
\\&=|\sin a \cdot\cosh b+i \sinh b \cdot \cos a|
\\&=\sqrt{(\sin a \cdot\cosh b)^2+(\sinh b \cdot \cos a)^2}
\\&\ge |\sin a |\cdot|\cosh b|
\\&\ge |\sin a\:|=|\sin (\text{Re}\:z)\:|
\end{align}
$$ using that $\cosh x\ge1$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Dante You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $z=x+iy$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R$.  Then
\begin{align}
\sin z & = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = \frac{e^{ix-y} - e^{-ix+y}}{2i} = \frac{e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x) - e^y(\cos x - i\sin x)}{2i} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{(e^{-y} - e^y)\cos x + i(e^{-y}+e^y)\sin x}{2i}
\end{align}
This is at least as large in absolute value than the absolute value of its real part.  Its real part is
$$
\frac {e^{-y}+e^y} 2 \sin x.
$$
If you can show that $\dfrac{e^{-y}+e^y} 2 \ge 1$, then the thing above is $\ge \sin x = \sin(\operatorname{Re}(z)). $